# Есть ли API для сайта 4pda.ru

Tags: ios, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Я начал разработку приложения для iOS - читалку новостей с сайта 4pda.ru, но у меня нет API этого сайта. Если у кого-то есть какая-то информация по API этого сайта или как его можно получить буду очень признателен, спасибо!

Comment: Написать администраторам сайта или владельцам?

Comment: не имеет отношения к программированию/администрированию